# Angular 4 ng build with one environment file for different environments

Tags: angularjs, json, environment

In our project `ng build` run 4-5 minutes at least. For creation builds for 5 environments we need wait 20-25 minutes.

`ng build` command create dist directory.

If it possible to run `ng build` for one environment, but in the environment. ts file gets properties from a JSON file.

In this way, I will create one build and will add for each environment only JSON file. This needs to be more quickly because I only create zip files from dist directory with different JSON file. and not make build 5 times.

Any idias?
Thanks